# How can I pass parameters into these functions called via dictionary lookup

Tags: python

I need to be able to get at all the parameters passed into my function, make_choice.  But on line 25 (requesterverb) I am getting runtime error:

```
requester[verb](kwargs)
TypeError: doPUT() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#switch using dictionary
def make_choice(verb, **kwargs):
    def doGET(**kwargs):
        print "Doing GET"
        for key in kwargs:
            print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])

    def doPUT(**kwargs):
        print "Doing PUT"
        for key in kwargs:
            print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])

    def doDELETE(**kwargs):
        print "Doing DELETE"  

    def doPOST(**kwargs):
        print "Doing POST"

    def doPATCH(**kwargs):
        print "Doing PATCH"  

    requester = { 'GET': doGET, 'PUT': doPUT }

    requester[verb](kwargs)


make_choice(verb='PUT',param1='param1',param2='param2',param3='param3')
print "done"
```

Comment: Since `verb` is a named positional argument, I think it is cleaner to do this `make_choice('PUT',param1='param1',param2='param2',param3='param3')`.  Otherwise, people using your code will think `verb` is a keyword argument.

Comment: Unless have good reason (e.g., dynamically updating the logic of the `doX` functions based on the input to `make_choice`), I would suggest moving all the `doX` functions out of `make_choice`. Otherwise, `make_choice` will construct each of those `doX` functions every time it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `**` before `kwargs` in:

```
requester[verb](**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Do you know what is happening when I pass **kwargs rather than kwargs (or even *kwargs)?  ie what is the difference?

Comment: It's called "keyword argument unpacking".

Comment: @user619818 when used as function parameter, `kwargs` is "normal dictionary", passed as one argument. When used with 2 asterisks as `**kwargs`, it means "pass each key:value pair as a **keyword arguments**. And since `doXXX` functions have no "normal arguments" (0) it raises exception when you try to add "just some dictionary". When using special syntax, it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

In `make_choice` scope, `kwargs` is a dictionary containing your `paramX` vaules and keys.
So in this function scope, `kwargs` is nothing more than a dictionary.

Just remove the `**` before the `kwargs` in the arguments of your `doXXX` functions, and it will work.

Comment: If I do that I get runtime error:  TypeError: make_choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param1'

Comment: You have to keep the `**` in the make_choice signature.

Comment: And yet, I just tested it and it works just fine. What is wrong? Is it non-pythonic?

Comment: @JanSpurny: I don't see what's wrong with this answer. It's purely a style issue whether you want to change the signatures of the `doXXX` functions to work with the existing `requester[]()` call, or change the call to work with the existing signatures. It's true that fixing the signatures requires *more changes* to the OP's code than fixing one call... but that's a far cry from "very, very wrong".

Comment: @JohnY: Those `doXXX` functions in the questions are obviously just a dummy versions. But in real application, you want to write them differently, for example as: `def doGET(session_id = None, **kwargs):`. With using one dictionary parameter, you're forcing all `doXXX` functions to comply with your artificial constraint - a single dictionary argument. When using `**kwargs`, `doXXX` functions authors have more freedom and they can write those functions to be easier to understand. Also, since `kwargs` has special meaning in python, it's confusing.

Comment: @Shaac I personally don't like arguing if something is `pythonic` or not. I'd rather say your solution is a bit confusing (you're using argument `kwargs` which is NOT `**kwargs`) and introduces new constraint on `doXXX` functions. Which is 2 bad things in my opinion. See my comment above in reply to JohnY.